# Programming a Discord bot with Python- How do I make it join a voice channel?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make the bot join the voice channel that I'm in when prompted. Here's what I have:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('.join'):
    channel = 775902254951301125
    await channel.connect()
```

It doesn't seem to work, any tips?

Comment: Hello ! Can you be more specific about what you mean by "doesn't work"? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? Answering these questions will help us understand your issue.

Comment: When I trigger the command I expect the bot to join the voice channel, but it gives me this instead-

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'connect'.

Comment: "channel" in the code above is just a plain number. You seem to want to call a method (`.connect()`) on it, as if it was some kind of object related to the discord.py library. You probably forgot to call some function from the library with this number. First thing I recommend would be to check the documentation for an example.

Comment: Oh. That number was the ID of the voice channel, but I guess it doesn't work like that. I tweaked the code:
`@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.content.startswith('.join'):
    channel = author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()`
Now it tells me that 'author' isn't defined. How would I go about defining it? (Sorry I'm new to programming)

Comment: Since you are trying to get the author of the **message**, try `message.author.voice.channel` instead 

Comment: Your current channel is not a valid channel. use `channel = await message.guild.get_channel(channel_id)`

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for!

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.voice_channel
    await client.join_voice_channel(channel)
```

That was pulled straight from this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFVby_Vet7E) which was just a google search away.

Comment: I tried this out, and it gives me an error:
`AttributeError: 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'`

Comment: I don't think the op is using the bot commands framework.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '>')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print ("Log : "+str(client.user))
  ch = await client.fetch_channel("enter id voice channel")
  await ch.connect()


client.run('token')
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).