# Open Discord and make user join a specific voice channel

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to open discord and join a voice channel with a voice command. All I find is about bots, while I'm trying to do it with the user, me, in this case. Opening discord is not a problem, but I have no idea of how to do the voice channel thing, I'm still a begginer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65729028/programming-a-discord-bot-with-python-how-do-i-make-it-join-a-voice-channel

Answer (score 1):

First of all, discord does not allow you execute client side commands directly or more specifically, pull users to voice channels. Making an user force-join a voice channel via a command would be a serious security exploit.

What you can do to make users join channels, is to let them join a waiting room of some sort, than pulling them to channels from there.

Now as far as i understand, you want to join a specific channel via a voice command yourself. In that case i would suggest not using discord API. I would implement a web scraper (in this case something like a web scraper would suffice since discord is basically running its website as an app, Press Ctrl+Shift+I and you will understand what i mean) to target a text containing the voice channel name i want to join. I would get that name from voice recognition. Then get that text position on screen and click it. You could use pyautogui for that purpose.

To be fair, this is not a beginner project at all, however with sufficient research and work you can make it.

Cheers

Comment: Not so.  You can create a token and give the discord bot access to move channels, create or delete.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65729028/programming-a-discord-bot-with-python-how-do-i-make-it-join-a-voice-channel

Comment: Making bots join channels, create or delete them is possible. However I think OP wants to join a channel with a voice command i.e say something and make the bot move them.  You can do the waiting room thing check out this link; https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.move_to  but without already being in a channel its impossible